# Why does the Ruby file have a NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby

I have a lesson file for an in-terminal tic-tac-toe game. my lib file works when I isolate it. (lib/move.rb)

```
def display_board(board)
  puts " #{board[0]} | #{board[1]} | #{board[2]} "
  puts "-----------"
  puts " #{board[3]} | #{board[4]} | #{board[5]} "
  puts "-----------"
  puts " #{board[6]} | #{board[7]} | #{board[8]} "
end 

def input_to_index(user_input)
  index = user_input.to_i - 1
end

def move(arr,ind,char = "X")
  arr[ind] = char
end
```

However, when I run my bin file (bin/move), a NoMethodError shows up referencing the "index = user_input.to_i -1"

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require_relative '../lib/move.rb'

# Code your CLI Here
puts "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!"

board = Array.new(9," ")

puts "Where would you like to go?"

input = gets.split

index = input_to_index(input)

input_to_index(input)

move(board,index,"X")

display_board(board)
```

I don't understand what's wrong and how to fix it.

//#input_to_index is meant to turn the input into an integer, and takes input 1-9 and outputs 0-8
Please help!

Comment: what is the exact error message you are getting? running under ruby 2.6.3, I am getting a `undefined method to_i for ["1"]:Array (NoMethodError)` which makes sense as `gets.split` returns an array, and array doesn't have a to_i. I am confused when you say it works when you isolate it, works how? try removing the gets.split, and just calling to_i on the string returned from gets, and see if that does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**split** divides string(read from user input, the gets method) into substrings based on a delimiter, returning an array of these substrings. **to_i** is a method of string that covert it to an integer value, which is not available to an array.

Try to change

```
gets.split
```

to

```
gets
```

Then the issue will go away.